# How to pass Ordinal_Position values dynamically to a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run below query to dynamically fetch the column name depending on their ORDINAL_POSITION.

```
declare @data_col nvarchar(max),
@id int
set @id=1
print @id
set @data_col='select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=''Source_table'' and ORDINAL_POSITION='+@id+''

exec sp_executeSQL @data_col
```

This doesn't seems to work. Is there any alternate method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `sp_executesql`.  Use parameters!

```
declare @data_col nvarchar(max), @id int;
set @id = 1;
print @id;
set @data_col = '
select column_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = ''Source_table'' and
      ORDINAL_POSITION = @id
';

exec sp_executeSQL @data_col, N'@id integer', @id = @id;
```

I think I would also pass the table in as a parameter, but there is no harm in hard coding it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this instead

```
DECLARE @data_col NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @id INT
SET @id = 1
PRINT @id

SET @data_col = 'select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=''Source_table'' and ORDINAL_POSITION=@id'

EXEC sp_executesql @data_col,
    N'@id int', @id;
```